# Use AWS s3 image_url for production and development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I upload images through an admin feature on production. I then use `pg_restore` to pull down my production database to my local db. The problem is that now all my image links are broken in development. I would like my dev environment to use the AWS s3 image urls for both production and development.

Looking inside the consoles, I see this:

Local Rails Console

```rb
$ Image.last.photo.url
$ "/assets/products/3/product/__35.JPG?1415467267"
```

Heroku Console

```rb
$ Image.last.photo.url
$ "https://s3.amazonaws.com/app_name/app/public/assets/products/3/product/__35.JPG?1415467267"
```

I'm using the following relevant gems:
paperclip, asset_sync, and rmagick

My Image class is using paperclip for storage:

```rb
has_attached_file :photo, PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTS
```

The Storage options are the same in development.rb and production.rb

```rb
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTS = {  
  :styles => {:mini => '48x48>',
    :small    => '100x100>',
    :medium   => '200x200>',
    :product  => '320x320>',
    :large    => '600x600>' },
  :default_style => :product,
  :url => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost posted this question and then figured it out. Felt I should share, in case anyone else comes across the same issue.

In my `config/environments/production.rb` I had:

```rb
config.after_initialize do
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3
end
```

The above code should be added to `config/environments/development.rb` also!

Now edit the image `:path` in that same `development.rb` file with `app` instead of `:rails_root`:

```rb
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTS = {  
  # :styles, :default_style, and :url are the same as above 
  :path => "app/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
}
```